# What amp rating ESC do I need?

Tags: pwm, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am working on an electric longboard, retaining the original battery pack and brushless hub motors. I want to be able to control this with an Arduino. I want to know what size ESC I will need. The battery pack is 30V and the hub motors have a 1200W rating each. Will a 50Amp ESC be sufficient for each motor?

Comment: That depends a lot on the conditions and qualifcations of usage and the ratings you give - a big problem is that those are marketing driven hobby product ratings, *not* engineering ratings, so unless you can find an actual data sheet (and be confident a given example will meet it) it is hard to give an engineering answer, vs. simply looking at what worked for other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why we have Ohm's Law:  I = P/E

- P = Power (Watts)
- E = Electromotive Force (Volts)
- I = Current (Amps)

You can calculate any of the factors given two factors:

[image]

I made an Ohm's Law calculator online here: http://www.rcrowley.com/eirp.htm

If you plug in 30V and 1200W, it shows that the current is 40A.
So your 50A ESC should be adequate.

Comment: Feel free to reveal why you voted this down????